# socket.emit('event', message, callback )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I was following a youtube tutorial where a callback function is passed with socket.emit, the callback changes one of the states of the component

```
    socket.emit('event', message, () => changeState())
```

on the server side, this callback is called

```
 socket.on('event', (message, callback) => {
    // some code
    callback()
})
```

how does this work?
How can the state change by calling the callback in server side?
Is this wrong or am I unaware of some functionality?

Comment: I use it alot is very handy.. tip check its a function else if its not, it will crash the server: `if (typeof callback === 'function') callback()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
socket.emit(eventName[, …args][, ack])
```

You don't pass the callback (`ack`) to the server, its a callback which called with server's response. [See related docs (Client)](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack):

> The ack argument is optional and will be called with the server answer.

And [on server](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/):

> The ack argument is optional and will be called with the client’s answer.

So basically in your example, he just doesn't use the server's response argument, in other words: "set state on server's response".

```
// Client
socket.emit('event', message, (serverResponse) => change())

// Server, callback is **NOT** the callback above.
socket.emit('event', message, (clientResponse) => callback())
```

Comment: so the function from the server is send as the ack message and the callback on the client side is executed (asuming client emitted the event as in the qns) ??

Comment: so ack message is actually sent from the server which when received by the client executes its callback.